# Ionic Chooser Plugin not returning base64 string on Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic-native, capacitor, filepicker

I am using the `"@ionic-native/chooser": "^5.25.0"` package in my **Ionic Capacitor app** to select and then upload files. I need the file content to be encoded in **base64 string format**, however strangely enough this is only happening for iOS and **not Android**?

I am using **Ionic v5** and **Capacitor 2.0.1**.

This is the json response I get on Android after selecting a file:

`{data: Uint8Array(0), mediaType: "application/pdf", name: "standard-tube-map.pdf", uri: "content://com.dropbox.android.FileCache/filecache/3a2ef683-16b6-4b01-bd4c-69a0a03e2da1", dataURI: "data:application/pdf;base64,"}`

As you can see the **value** for the `dataURI` field should include the base64 string at the end of the string, however it seems to be missing: `"data:application/pdf;base64,"`.

Anyone having the same issue? How did you solve it?

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Same issue here, it works fine on iOS, but not in Android, I'm using it wirh cordova. I tried it in a new project and it's working fine for Android, I don't know if it's crashing due to other plugins.